# How to get the list of views from flask_view_counter?

Tags: javascript, python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using `flask_view_counter` to track all the views. It saves to the database properly, however, I can not get all the views inside the program. I have tried to do it using SQLAlchemy, but mostly it uses models to find information from database.
Here is the example of code:

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Views</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>All the views: {{ my_views }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_view_counter import ViewCounter
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
views = ViewCounter(app, db)

@app.route('/')
@views.count
def mai():
    my_views = None # how to get it???
    return render_template('main.html', my_views=my_views)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If there is another way to make a view counter using python or javascript, I would like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The `flask_view_counter` code is [fairly simple](https://gitlab.com/shiftlesscode/flask-view-counter/-/blob/master/flask_view_counter.py#L30): it creates a database table and inserts a new record every time your flask view was called. There is no model – or, `declarative extension` in terms of SQLAlchemy, – as you would expect. To fetch the records, you would need to [select from the table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#selecting) directly.

The reference to the table is available as an attribute on the `ViewCounter` instance. In your case, it would be `views.requests`. You can pass the table object to `sqlalchemy.sql.select` and run a query with `db.engine.execute`.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_view_counter import ViewCounter
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
views = ViewCounter(app, db)

@app.route('/')
@views.count
def mai():
    my_views = db.engine.execute(select([views.requests]))
    return render_template('main.html', my_views=my_views)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There are many other options for counting views available, it depends on your use case, of course. As a simple solution, you could use the more intrusive Google Analytics JS library. You could look into counting the views [in pure python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680357/increment-counter-for-every-access-to-a-flask-view) without caching them. In case you don't want to use `SQLAlchemy` you could even roll your own view decorator based on the [`flask_view_counter`'s source code](https://gitlab.com/shiftlesscode/flask-view-counter/-/blob/master/flask_view_counter.py) and store data somewhere else.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. It frows an error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: columns argument to select() must be a Python list or other iterable`

Answer (score 0):

So, the result should be modified from solution above:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_view_counter import ViewCounter
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
views = ViewCounter(app, db)

@app.route('/')
@views.count
def main():
    func = select([views.requests])
    my_views = db.engine.execute(func)
    return render_template('main.html', my_views=my_views)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Views</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for view in my_views %}
        <h1>All each ip for view: {{ view.ip }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've corrected my answer accordingly, you can delete this one