# Flask: if I count requests I can't do multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, request

I have a Flask API that should get a request, do some stuff with selenium, and then return something to the user.

**VERSION 1**

```
import flask
from multiprocessing import Value
from selenium import webdriver

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = False
@app.route('/api/url', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def site():
    # do some stuff ...
    with open(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "\\file.mp3"), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(<something>)
    # ... do some other stuff and return a variable

def home():
    return "<h1>Distant Reading Archive</h1><p>This site is a prototype API for distant reading of science fiction novels.</p>"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", threaded=True)
```

This code would technically work perfectly, if it wasn't that I need to manage multiple requests at once: for example, if I have  two requests that are being processed in the same time, the second request would overwrite the file on the file created by the first request and that would be a problem.

**VERSION 2**

To avoid that all the threads overwrite the same file, I changed the code by including the `counter` variable that acts like a request counter (from this answer [Increment counter for every access to a Flask view - answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683497/12664376)).

The following code will create a file named `file<n>.mp3` for each request, where `<n>` is the number of the request (the `<n>`-th request), and so I will have a different file for each request.

```
import flask
from multiprocessing import Value
from selenium import webdriver

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = False
@app.route('/api/url', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

counter = Value('i', 0)

def site():
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1
        out = counter.value
        # do some stuff ...
        with open(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "\\file{}.mp3".format(out)), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(<something>)
        # ... do some other stuff and return a variable

def home():
    return "<h1>Distant Reading Archive</h1><p>This site is a prototype API for distant reading of science fiction novels.</p>"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", threaded=True)
```

**PROBLEMS WITH VERSION 2**

The problem with version 2 of the code is that multithreading apparently stops working, and the code processes only one request at time.

The fact that multithreading stopped working seems related to the fact that I have included the counter, because in version 1 multithreading did actually work and the API processed all the different requests separately (but the code still didn't behave as I wanted to because of the overwriting problem)

**QUESTION**

How can I count all the requests and still manage to process each of them on its own/with its file, while having multiple requests being processed at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have too much code wrapped inside `with counter.get_lock()`.  For as long as you have this lock, no other thread can run.

Instead you want:

```
with counter.get_lock():
    counter.value += 1
    out = counter.value
do rest of the stuff outside of the lock
```