# How can i count how many time i've reloaded page in python Flask?

Tags: python, flask

so i'm creating simple web page using Flask, just for practice and i have this little problem.
i want to count how many times i've reloaded page. for example:

```
count = 0
@app.route("/")
def home():
    print(count)
    count += 1
    return "testing"
```

but this doesn't work. if you guys know anything about it please help. <3 Thanks!

Comment: You could check how many requests you are getting from a particular ip address. However, a front end approach shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript might be better, then you could send a request to the server whenever the browser detects the reload. This might not be easier than the IP address method, but might make users feel more "safe"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests could help

Comment: in that code i have a list. and i want to print next item from list, everytime user reloads the page. and i thougt i would use counter and maybe use that as index of list <3 i hope i understand it well :D <3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't the problem related to the flask. It's related to the python global variable. You just need to access your global variable declared globally inside the function using the `global` variable. Check [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) for more details related to python variable types.

The code can be updated as

```
count = 0
@app.route("/")
def home():
    global count
    print(count)
    count += 1
    return "testing"
```

Note: The best practice for concurrent users is to avoid using the `global` variable. Instead, use python [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683497/9166673)

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach. What happens if you have 4 working processes for example?

Answer (score 0):

the above code will work, but since you are trying to access the `count` variable from a function, you need to declare in the function that its a `global`:

```
count = 0
@app.route("/")
def home():
    global count
    print(count)
    count += 1
    return "testing"
```

more info on global variables [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)